# Прочитать пакет отправленный, используя сокеты, из Java в Питоне: Java -> Python

Tags: java, python, сокет, utf-8

Всем привет, задался таким вопросом, как мне в моём коде на Python прочитать сообщение, которое я отправил с Java приложения, код ниже:

Этим кодов отправляю, код Java:

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {

private static Socket socket;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    DataOutputStream os = null;
    socket = new Socket("localhost", 500);
    os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    os.writeUTF("Test");         
   }
}
```

Тут принимаю отправленный пакет, код Python:

```
import socket, os
s = socket.socket()
s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 500))
s.listen(5)
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    data = c.recv(1024)
    print(str(data))
```

P.S

Обычным replace тут не обойтись, тк там передается длинна сообщения.

Comment: Код должен быть прямо в тексте вопроса без ссылок на сторонние ресурсы

Comment: А также внятный заголовок и описание проблемы, с которой вы столкнулись.

Comment: А в чем ошибка? Кст, вроде бы, порты до 1000 системные

Comment: Я получаю ответ в виде 

b'\x00\x04Test'

А мне нужно, что-бы было просто написано "Test"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Метод [writeUTF](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF-java.lang.String-) отправляет строку в кодировке [modified UTF-8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#modified-utf-8), а потому хорош только в тех случаях, когда на другой стороне принимает данные тоже java-код.

```
String data = "Test";
try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 5000)) {
    try (DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())) {
        os.write(data.getBytes("utf-8"), 0, data.length());
    }
}
```

И на стороне python-кода вместо `print(str(data))` использовать `print(data.decode('utf-8'))`.

Answer (score -2):

Решил костылем, но **ВСЕ-ЖЕ РАБОЧИМ**

```
data = str(c.recv(1024)).split('*')[1].replace("'", "")
```

Comment: не используйте str() с bytes объектом — это ошибка. Не путайте двоичные данные и текст. Как bytes в текст превратить зависит от используемого протокола. Лучше использовать протоколы которые от языка не зависят такой как http (зависит от приложения что лучше подходит).